# React-Native: If MobX @observable variables are temporary and have an expiration time?

Tags: react-native, mobx

I'm using **MobX** in recent React Native projects for state management. I would like to know is the `@observable` variables are temporary and have an expiration time (after that they are self-deleted by MobX).
Can MobX be used also for offline duties like SQLite?
 What would be the difference between using SQLite and MobX in a React Native project?

Answer (score 0):

An `@observable` property has no more permanence than an ordinary property. The only difference is it can notify when it is changed, allowing code that has read the property to come back and re-read it to get the new value. For example, a component that read the value when rendering will need to re-render using the new value. Or a `@computed` property will need to re-compute.

An `@observable` property does not use any special external storage. It's just an ordinary value in memory, just like an undecorated property. So this has nothing much in common with SQLite or any other persistent storage.